# Grep -E yielding different results on SuSE Linux

Tags: linux, suse

I recently updated a SuSE server to 11.3 from 11.0. I updated to 11.1, then 11.2, then 11.3. Anyway my question is when I run a grep -E command on this server it returns incorrect results. When I run the same command on a different server (running 11.0) it returns the correct result. See below.

```
DOW=Wed ; if [[ -z $(echo $DOW | grep -E $(date +%a)) ]] ; then ; echo hello ; else ; echo  
nothello ; fi
```

When I run the command on the 11.3 server I get:

```
"Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
hello"
```

When I run the command on the server running 11.0 I get:

```
"nothello"
```

Any ideas to what the issue is?

Comment: I'd guess that `date +%a` has stopped working.

Comment: @Wumpus Q. Wumbley I have actually already verified that 'date +%a' is not the problem. It is functioning properly on both systems.

Comment: Then I suggest using `set -x` to see what commands are actually being run

Comment: By "SuSE server 11.3", do you mean "SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 Service Pack 3" or "openSUSE 11.3"?

Comment: I mean "SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 Service Pack 3".